# What made the first Command fail?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, terminal, superuser

I decided to clear my data usage stats on my Android in `Settings > Data Usage` from the [terminal emulator app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en), but the first command came back with the error "No such file or directory".

The first command: `rm /data/system/netstats/*`

The same command that worked: `rm /data/system/netstats/*`

Here's a screenshot of what happened.

[image]

I'm running the [supernexus custom ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/development/rom-supernexus-4-0-i9300-build-1-t2583606) on android 4.4.2 on my Samsung Galaxy S3-19300

I was sure of the directory to clear of the stats but had to try a different directory in the latter commands, and the same command worked fine in the last line, what could've caused this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell for sure without "direct access", but here are the most likely answers:

1. there are no files in that directory, so nothing to remove
2. you cannot use `rm` to remove directories (that's what `rmdir` is for)
3. that will most likely fail as well, since `/system` is usually mounted read-only ;)
4. the original command succeeded at last: most likely some file was created there in the meantime.